# Datanitro raises "Failed to connect/bind"

Tags: datanitro

I just installed datanitro but I keep getting the following error when I try to open a shell:

> Failed to connect/bind
>   ...

This msg also raises when I try to execute a script.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: not expert but have installed it few times.   Have had similar problems occasionally.   Simple un-install and reinstall normally works.   There are sometimes some files left in the c:\programFiles (x86) after uninstall.   Clear those as well and reinstall.   alos try toggling using the DataNitro and the make sure you are setting the correct path to your python install in the Settings